# Нужна ли запятая после "вот"? [1]

Tags: пунктуация

> Вот(,) что создает атмосферу!!!

Comment: Отличное разъяснение! Пожалуй сохраню Ваш сайт в закладках и постараюсь сюда почаще заглядывать! С Уважением, Юрий!;)

Answer (score 4):

Запятая не нужна, т. к. здесь *вот* усиливает эмоциальную окрашенность.

> Запятая ставится после слова *вот*, если следующее за ним предложение раскрывает его конкретный смысл: *Вот,  можете полюбоваться на своего
>   сынка;  Вот,  возьмите эту книгу на добрую память*.
>
> Но: *Вот аптека; Вот раздался удар грома; Вот взгляните; Вот ещё что
>   затеял!; Вот оно что*, где *вот* — частица с указательным значением.
>
> В отдельных случаях возможны варианты пунктуации; ср.:
>
> *Вот,  кончились наши запасы* (пауза после *вот*). — *Вот кончились наши
>   запасы*;
>
> *Ну вот,  теперь можно поговорить о делах*. — *Ну  вот  теперь можно
>   поговорить о делах*.

Подробнее [здесь](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827513.html#id-%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%97%D0%94%D0%95%D0%9B8%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85-%C2%A729%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B02).

Comment: Можно еще добавить что отсутствие запятой можно проверить по смыслу, если можно заменить "что" на субъект речи. "Вот эта деталь создает атмосферу". В таком варианте  роль усиления смазывается,  на язык просится еще одна частица для создания ударения "Вот эта деталь и создает атмосферу". Видно, что в этом случае "что" - не союз.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая не нужна: **Вот что создает атмосферу!!!**

ВОТ, частица.  2. (обычно ударная) (с местоим. и нареч.). Употребляется для уточнения и усиления значения последующего слова или высказывания в целом. **Вот что я тебе скажу**.  3. (с частицами и местоим. **в восклиц. предл.)**. Употребляется **для усиления** восхищения, **удивления**, недоумения, разочарования, пренебрежения и т.п. Вот это новость!

Comment: Порой на "вот" логическое ударение, для усиления указательности.